# How to dual boot windows 8 and ubuntu 12.10 on HP pavilion 14-b010TX

Tags: 12.10, dual-boot, windows, hp

I've used Ubuntu on my old Compaq V26633TN for a few years, but it's wearing out after 9 years use.
I've bought a replacement HP Pavilion 14-b010TX (CD58PA) with factory installed Windows 8 and mSATA 32GB and HDD 750GB. I got HP service to add another 4GB of RAM (now 8GB) and they didn't adjust the Intel RST raid0 array from 4GB to 8GB which after a while I fixed.
I'd like to keep Windows 8, but mainly work on Ubuntu so I am after a dual boot UEFI system.

When installing 12.10 I tried to partition the HDD to have Windows on the first 100GB then Ubuntu on the next 100GB and hope to have the remainder for files, photos, etc.

from just after installation http://paste.ubuntu.com/5651599/

```
sda1:419MB:ntfs:Basic data partition:hidden, diag;
sda2:273MB:fat32:EFI system partition:boot;
sda3:134MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
sda4:100GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:;
sda6:300MB:ext4::;
sda7:100GB:ext4::;
sda8:8000MB:linux-swap(v1)::;
sda5:27.2GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:hidden;
sdb1:33.6MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
sdb2:8590MB::Basic data partition:;
```

Here's a summary of how it went.

At first I could access Windows but not Ubuntu so made changes with easyBCD then boot repair from a live USB
It then booted into Ubuntu but not Windows

Choosing "system setup" in grub menu -> F9 -> troubleshoot -> windows repairs I could boot into windows but not ubuntu

I ran easyBCD to set windows default os, deleted the previous ubuntu, then added (grub 2) ubuntu using the auto find boot option. Now the option to boot to windows has disappeared and Ubuntu 12.10 is now 2 options in Windows Boot Manager (and HP system setup interface) neither work but return errors

```
Windows Boot Manager  

Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.  
To fix the problem:

  1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
  2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
  3. Click "repair your computer."

If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer
manufacturer for assistance. 

  File: \NST\AutoNeoGrub1.mbr    

  Status: 0xc000000f   

  Info: The application or operating system couldn't be loaded because a required  
        file is missing or contains errors.
```

Pressing Esc goes to the HP System Settings menu where:
Continue to Ubuntu 12.10 (on volume 4) goes back to the above errors.
Choose an operating system gives the same option twice: Ubuntu 12.10 on volume 4. (it used to also give Windows 8) . 
Use a device gives the options: Internal HD or SSD twice or Ubuntu (using this option I can get into Grub2 then Ubuntu).
I get the two options for Ubuntu also under Troubleshoot -> Recovery manager and Advanced options -> System Restore or System Image Recovery or Automatic Repair.

In Ubuntu I had a kernel panic whenever attempting to connect to the internet due to rt3290 wireless driver not working. Updated the Kernel to 3.9 and it now works OK.

I did a recommended boot repair

It now boots straight to Windows Boot Manager with the 2 options of Ubuntu or Ubuntu and neither work.

I can get to ubuntu via Esc -> *HP system settings* -> *Use a device* -> *Ubuntu* -> *GRUB menu* -> *Ubuntu*. Then there are some errors before the Ubuntu loading screen:

```
udevd[107]: sender uid=65534, message ignored
[    9.946587] kvm: disabled by bios
[    9.950349] kvm: disabled by bios
[    9.962701] kvm: disabled by bios
[    9.970359] kvm: disabled by bios
[   10.164945] nouveau I[  DEVICE][0000:01:00.0] unknown Fermi chipset
[   10.164993] nouveau E[  DEVICE][0000:01:00.0] unknown chipset, 0x0d70000a2
[   10.165034] nouveau E[     DRM]failed to create 0x80000080, -22
```

http://paste.ubuntu.com/5670228/

```
etc/defaults/grub/grub file details:
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

I'm guessing I need to get grub as the default boot menu back then find the correct efi file for Windows?
I'm all out of ideas and don't know where to from here. Any help would be appreciated.